# How to use async function with mutation and image upload react js

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have to upload images in the directory and save that name into a database using graphql resolver. When I upload an image and pass that image in resolver but I am getting an undefined value of image name. So how can I get the image name?

In the Below code, I saved information with file upload but a problem to get a file name after uploading an image. So how can I get the file uploaded file name?

```
const fs = require("fs");

function ProfileImage(argsprofilephoto) {
    try {
        argsprofilephoto.then(profilephoto => {
            const {
                createReadStream,
                filename,
                mimetype
            } = profilephoto;
            const fileStream = createReadStream();
            fileStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./uploadedFiles/${filename}`));
            console.log("filename=", filename);
            return filename;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

export default {
    Mutation: {
        signUp: async (parent, args, {
            models,
            secret
        }) => {
            try {
                let profimgnm = "";
                let docimgnm = "";
                // Prfile Photo  Upload
                if (args.profilephoto != "") {
                    profimgnm = ProfileImage(args.profilephoto);
                    console.log("profimgnm=", profimgnm);
                }
                if (args.documents != "") {
                    docimgnm = ProfileImage(args.documents);
                    console.log("docimgnm=", docimgnm);
                }

                let name = args.name;
                let email = args.email;
                let phone = args.phone;
                let address = args.address;
                let zipcode = args.zipcode;
                let profilephoto = profimgnm;
                let documents = docimgnm;
                const user = await models.User.create({
                    name,
                    email,
                    phone,
                    address,
                    zipcode,
                    profilephoto,
                    documents
                });
                return user;
            } catch (err) {}
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting this output.

```
profimgnm= undefined
docimgnm= undefined
filename= download.jpg
filename= dimg.jpg
```

Anyone, please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here. You are not returning the promise from ProfileImage async method. You should be doing something like:

```
function ProfileImage(argsprofilephoto) {
    return argsprofilephoto.then(profilephoto => {
            const {
                createReadStream,
                filename,
                mimetype
            } = profilephoto;
            const fileStream = createReadStream();
            fileStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./uploadedFiles/${filename}`));
            console.log("filename=", filename);
            return filename;
        }).catch(e => {
       // you might want to return some sensible default depending on your usecase, or let the error bubble up by not catching 
       console.log(e)
    });
}
```

and in your resolver you need to wait for the promise to resolve:

```
if (args.profilephoto != "") {
  // could still be undefined if the promise above failed on catch block returned nothing, but you get the idea
  profimgnm = await ProfileImage(args.profilephoto);
  console.log("profimgnm=", profimgnm);
}
if (args.documents != "") {
  docimgnm = await ProfileImage(args.documents);
  console.log("docimgnm=", docimgnm);
}
```